# "Inside" in the role of an adverb or a noun?

Tags: prepositions, adverbs, nouns, prepositional-phrases

Consider the sentences below:

> 1. wipe the inside of the fridge.
> 2. wipe inside the fridge.

In the first sentence, ***inside*** is a noun but in the second one, is an adverb.

Now,what is the difference between the first one and the second?

Is the second sentence correct grammatically?

Comment: what you will be sweeping, where you will be sweeping.

Comment: for example,house.

Comment: *sweep* might not be the best word in this context, since in a household context sweeping is usually done with a broom. More likely it is cleaning of some kind.

Comment: Both are grammatical. Trust [the dictionary!](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/inside?s=t)  As a noun: _the inner or internal part; interior._ As a preposition: _within._

Comment: No, never trust a dictionary for determining a word's category (part of speech). Most dictionaries get it wrong when it comes to the prep/adverb/conjunction contrasts. "Inside" is a classic example; just look at Dictionary.com's definition of it in their example "Please go inside". They cluelessly give it as an adverb, when in fact it is an intransitive preposition. You've been warned!

Comment: Poor adverbs. They had it so good for a while. Now they feel as though the world has been turned inside-out.

Comment: Maybe it's a walk-in fridge :)

Comment: I'm really sorry.i meant to use the verb wipe instead of the verb sweep.I did that by accident.I don't know how did that.anyway,thanks.

Answer (score 2):

> 1-sweep **the inside** of the fridge

means to "sweep" in the interior parts of the fridge, such as the inner surfaces, shelves or drawers.

> 2-sweep **inside** the fridge

just means to "sweep" *something* that is inside the fridge.

1-is a noun, 2-is a preposition

Comment: the entry of http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/inside_1 is:Inside can be used in the following ways:
as a preposition (followed by a noun): What’s inside the envelope? Inside of is sometimes used instead of inside, especially in American English: ♦ I had a strange feeling inside of me.
as an adverb (without a following noun): I opened the box and looked inside.
as an adjective (always before a noun): the inside pages of a newspaper.

Comment: for this reason, inside is an adverb not preposition.

Comment: @ali In the very passage you quoted, it says: "...as an adverb **(without a following noun)**". In the example sentence you've written, "the fridge" is the following noun. It is, in this example, a preposition, not an adverb.